# Meaning of the phrase "it is worth noting that"

Tags: meaning

I'm a little bit confused with the following phrase. I was reading an article about concurrency in Java and there was a sentence saying:

> It is worth noting that both `unlockRead()` and `unlockWrite()` calls `notifyAll()` rather than `notify()`.

This phrase seemed quite strange to me. What does it mean?

Comment: It's a rather confusing text even for native speakers, because the writer is simultaneously using ***notifyAll*** as both a *noun* (the name of a function) and as a *verb* (with ***calls*** as the the subject). But the meaning of "It is worth noting that" is General Reference.

Comment: 1. *Calls* should be *call*, here (the subject is plural). 2. *It is worth noting that...* is a long way of saying *Note that...* or *Note:...*. Any writer who judges that it is worth pointing something out to the reader can just say *note:*.

Comment: Re plural:  I think this is specific jargon,  "both [A-type] and [B-type] calls [do X action] rather than [do Y action]."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"It is worth noting that"

simply means

- "here's something, which you should remember:" or
- "here's something you should pay attention to:" or
- "here's something that is worth reading and remembering:"

It's that simple.

Regarding (1), there is **no connection at all** to "apropos" or "besides..." Those have totally different, completely unrelated meanings.

Regarding (2), it always means exactly the same thing. It simply means "Here's an interesting point:"

(There is utterly no connection in any way to "useless" or "costs nothing".)

It is worth noting that, the ELL site exists for basic questions about the meanings of phrases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I get it :) Just one more question (which also tries to explain my thoughts about "useless" and "costs nothing"). "Worth" means "value" or "cost", right? So I thought when "worth" is "nothing", something is useless and has no value. Am I wrong?

Comment: I also read this as "nothing", not "noting". That's the reason for confusion.

Comment: OK, it has no connection at all to "nothing".  "worth noting" is a common phrase in spoken English (you'd never mistake it for "nothing" when hearing it.)

Comment: Something of "worth" has "value" or "**importance**."  To "note" something is to observe with in intent of **remembering**.  Therefore, something "worth noting" is "important to remember."  (Sometimes this may be abbreviated N.B. from the Latin phrase _nota bene_ for "note well".)

Comment: Sure, it's well-known what "worth" means.  In English you often say things like "it's worth finishing college" "it's worth having a Discover card" "it's worth the wait" "it's worth the paperwork" "it's worth having your wheels aligned" and so on.

Comment: To be pedantic: "worth noting" is not "abbreviated as" NB, rather, NB is (one of many) similes, common phrases, which mean the say thing.  ("be aware that" "be sure to" etc etc)